# How to add Permalink for custom content type(nodes)

Tags: 7, nodes

I need to add Permalink for my section/div where the ID will keep on changing whenever i update the page(custom content type).

I have achieved it through client side(Jquery) by find & get ID seems like tedious?

I have checked for module support like permalink & permalink block, Deeplink nothing seems to be helpful?

Is there is any better way to achieve it?

Comment: Jus to be clear, it's the fragment/anchor that will be changing, not the path, correct? E.g www.mysite.com/page-1#this-bit-changes

Comment: Yes exactly @mediaashley

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing (the logic) with jQuery? Because the solution I have assumes that the IDs are changing, so you don't know what they were previously.

Answer (score 0):

You can create permalinks, better known in the Drupal world as "aliases", using the [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module.

> The Pathauto module automatically generates URL/path aliases for
>   various kinds of content (nodes, taxonomy terms, users) without
>   requiring the user to manually specify the path alias. This allows you
>   to have URL aliases like /category/my-node-title instead of /node/123.
>   The aliases are based upon a "pattern" system that uses tokens which
>   the administrator can change.

See [Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJUYsJA737o).

Answer (score 0):

A custom theme preprocess function should help to process the page content and apply what you need (perhaps a numerical ID to each heading?).

Each node normally has a default permalink (regardless of url alias) of /node/[nid] which will automatically redirect to the actual path alias.  You can see an example of this in most themes with the `<link rel="shortlink" href="/node/[nid]" />` head element.

You could then permalink to individual pieces of content with `/node/[nid]#[heading id]`